# Varags Object Handling Oddness

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I don't think I understand how varargs is handling objects being passed in:

```
public class NoSense {

public static void someMethod(String a, Object... things) {

    System.err.println("a->" + a);

    System.err.println(things.getClass().getName());

    for (Object object : things) {
        System.err.println("thing->" + object);
    }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] x = new String[] { "what", "is", "up?" };
    NoSense.someMethod("1", x);
    NoSense.someMethod("2", x, "extra");
}
```

}

The results are

```
a->1
[Ljava.lang.String;
thing->what
thing->is
thing->up?
a->2
[Ljava.lang.Object;
thing->[Ljava.lang.String;@4d20a47e
thing->extra
```

Why would it treat the first set as a string array and the second as an object array reference?

Answer (score 2):

To maintain backwards compatibility, varargs is the last thing the compiler does to try to resolve a method call. Because the call `NoSense.someMethod("1", x);` can be resolved as `someMethod(String a, Object[] things)`, it is resolved as such. It can do this because array types are covariant.

The call `NoSense.someMethod("2", x, "extra");` however, can not be resolved as `someMethod(String a, Object[] things)`, and therefore uses varargs to create a `new Object[]{x, "extra"}`, which is then passed as the things parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `String[]` reference is implicitly convertible to `Object[]` via array covariance. The compiler doesn't need to use varargs, so it doesn't.

To *force* it to use varargs, we can just cast to `Object`:

```
    NoSense.someMethod("1", (Object) x);
```

Now `Object` isn't implicitly convertible to `Object[]`, so the compiler will wrap it in an array.

From section 15.12.4.2 of the JLS:

> If `m` is being invoked with k != n actual argument expressions, or, if m is being invoked with k == n actual argument expressions and the type of the kth argument expression is not assignment compatible with T[], then the argument list `(e1, ... , en-1, en, ...ek)` is evaluated as if it were written as `(e1, ..., en-1, new T[]{en, ..., ek})`.

Answer (score 1):

Because all parameters after the first are considered the values to be stored in the varargs array.  However, Java treats the case where only an array is passed as a special case and simply uses that as the varargs value.

**Case 1:**
Only one value is passed to a varargs of Object[]. This value is String[].  Java treats it as a special case and passes on the array directly.

**Case 2:**
Two values are passed to the varargs of Object[]. The first value is of type String[] and the second is of type String.  Since more than one value is being passed this is *not* a special case. So, the vargargs parameter is an Object[] (just as you defined it) with the first element being the passed string array and the second element being the string.